# Using Filling went wrong

Tags: plotting, regions, filling

```
f[x_] = If[x >= 0 && x <= 2, {4 - x^2, 2 x - x^2}];

p1 = Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic,
   PlotStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> 550, Filling -> {1 -> {2, Orange}},
    FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.1], Orange]];
p2 = Plot[{4 - x^2, 2 x - x^2}, {x, -3, 3}]; Show[{p1, p2}, 
 PlotRange -> {-2, 5}]
```

> Why do I get the area to the right colored?

Comment: `f` is a vector-valued function, not the scalar function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you return a list in your `f[x]`, Mathematica sees this as a single curve. You should explicitly provide two separate curves:

```
curves = {4 - x^2, 2 x - x^2};

p1 = Plot[curves, {x, -3, 3}];
p2 = Plot[curves, {x, 0, 2}, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Opacity[.2, Orange]}}];

Show[p1, p2, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Region` functionality as follows:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
curves = {4 - x^2, 2 x - x^2};
p3 = Plot[curves, {x, -3, 3}
  , Frame -> True
  , PlotStyle -> Thick
  , GridLines -> Automatic
  , ImageSize -> 550
  ];
reg = ImplicitRegion[
  y < First@curves && y >= Last@curves, {{x, 0, 2}, y}]
p4 = RegionPlot[reg
   , PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.4]]
   , BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]
   ];

Show[p3, p4]
```

[image]